# Laravel Mass update using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to mass update the record with the same foreign key. But I encounter a problem. If I use

```php
 $products = $products::findorfail($prod_id);
```

It manages to update a single column. Then when I trying using

```php
$products = $products::query()->where('product_id', $prod_id)->get();
```

I encounter `"Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::options does not exist.",` How do I overcome this problem.

Here is my current code

```php
    public function update(array $data = [],  $prod_id, Variation $products)
    {

        foreach ($data['variants'] as $product) {
            $products = $products::query()->where('product_id', $prod_id)->get();

            $products->options()->detach(($product['option_id']));
            $products->options()->attach(($product['option_id']));
            $products->fill(Arr::set($data, 'product_id', $prod_id));
            $products->fill(Arr::only($product, $products->getFillable()));
        }


        return $products->save();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get `first()` method to the one instance of the *Product* model and then attach or detach it to other things. Additionally, you can pass an array to attach or detach method for creating or removing relationship, so first gather the ids then pass them to these methods.

```
foreach ($data['variants'] as $product) {
    $option_ids[] = $product['option_id'];
}

$product = $products::query()
    ->where('product_id', $prod_id)
    ->first();

$product->options()->detach($option_ids);
$product->options()->attach($option_ids);
$product->fill(Arr::set($data, 'product_id', $prod_id));
$product->fill(Arr::only($product, $product->getFillable()));
```